# Array allocated by malloc is too long

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to copy string (and make its content uppercase) by the included code:

```
char* foo(char* word)
{
   int wordLength = strlen(word);
   char* result = (char*)malloc(wordLength * sizeof(char));
   for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; ++i)
      result[i] = toupper(word[i]);
   return result;
}
```

Variable `wordLength` contains correct number (exact number of letters in `word`), however `result` string is longer than `word` string and contains few (about 4) additional letters at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fail to terminate the copy.

Remember that C strings are arrays of characters terminated by a character with the numerical value 0.

Corrected code:

```
char * foo(const char *word)
{
  const size_t len = strlen(word);
  char *result = malloc(len + 1);
  char *put = result;
  while(len--)
   *put++ = toupper(*word++);
  *put = '\0';  /* This was missing! */
  return result;
}
```

This also uses the proper `size_t` type to handle string lengths, and simplifies the memory allocation. There's no need to scale by `sizeof (char)` (that's always 1) nor to cast the type of the result.

Comment: That was a problem. Thank you.

Comment: If this answer fixed your problem, you can accept it by clicking on the tick to the left.

Comment: But I can do this only after certain time from posting this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reserve space for the terminating zero and copy it from the source string to the destination array. Also as the source string is not changed in the function it should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

The function can look the following way

```
char* foo( const char* word )
{
    char* result = ( char* )malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );

    return strcpy( result, word );
}
```

Take into account that there is POSIX function `strdup` that does the same task.

If along with copying the string you need to convert it to the upper case then the function can look the following way

```
char* foo( const char *word )
{
    char* result = ( char* )malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );

    char *p = result;

    do 
    {
        *p++ = toupper( ( unsigned char )*word );
    } while ( *word++ );

    return result;
}
```

Or the function can be written using while loop instead of the do-while loop. For example

```
char* foo( const char *word )
{
    char* result = ( char* )malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );

    char *p = result;

    while ( ( *p++ = toupper( ( unsigned char )*word++ ) ) ); 

    return result;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* foo( const char *word )
{
    char* result = ( char* )malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );

    char *p = result;

    while ( ( *p++ = toupper( ( unsigned char )*word++ ) ) ); 

    return result;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char *s = foo( "hello world" );

    puts( s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: This totally fails to uppercase the string. And if you've gone to the trouble to call `strlen()`, it'd be better to use `memcpy()` to do the copying. :)

Comment: @unwind Oh< I have not seen that the string should be converted to uppercase.

Comment: You do not need the casts

Comment: @EdHeal What casts do you mean? The casts with malloc or casts with toupper?

Comment: The casts with malloc

Comment: @EdHeal If something can be used it does  not mean that it should be used. At least using the casting allows to use the function in C++ code.